# Expected value, wrong results

Tags: java, android

After reading some statistics about my app I saw that it takes over one month to update 75% of my users. Since all updates are very important I've come up to make an in-app alert that tells users that there is an update pending.

There is a text file containing the actual app version (18), stored in a webserver which is gotten by the `DownloadText()` method. This number goes in `isUpdatetxt` and is extracted from non-displayable characters with `.substring(1, 3)`. So basically, there's only "18" left.

But there is my problem: `isUpdatetxt == "18"` returns false, when it's not supposed to.

```
private class GetUpdate extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
{

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Vérification de mise à jours", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

        /** For debug reference*/
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "*" + isUpdatetxt + "*" + " " + (isUpdatetxt.length()), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
        if(isUpdatetxt == "18"){
            alertDialog.show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        isUpdatetxt = DownloadText(updateURL);
        isUpdatetxt = isUpdatetxt.substring(1, 3);
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: Only one way to find out why `'isUpdatetxt` doesn't equal "18"... Find out what it really contains by using a debug statement, log entry or some other mechanism.

Comment: using the debuger made me think that I can parse my number into an int which I should have do first. Thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are comparing Strings in Java, you should be using .equals().

When you compare strings with == in Java, you compare the references.

So your if-statement will be something like:

```
if(isUpdatetxt.equals("18")){
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

Comment: One of the things I like about C#... `==` actually works with strings as you would expect it to.